# Wamp server not working on windows 10 and it kils dns upon starting it

Tags: windows, dns, wamp

im having troubles making WAMPserver work.

Im currently running Win10.

Firstly I installed WAMP and it wouldnt go green, i googled and found that I should disable some windows features - World Wide Web Services specifically.

After I did that WAMP went green but `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` isnt working. Additionally I cant open any other website except facebook.com.

Im getting error no server response. Even when i turn off WAMP and stop all of its services problem with browsing remains.

Only fix is restart of PC.

So I cant use `localhost` and it kills my `dns`. Anyone got some hints what to do?

Comment: I can assure you WAMPServer does work with Windows10 so it must be something you have done wrong or not done. See [the troubleshooting page](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915) on the WAMPServer forum

Comment: yes, i installed wamp on my other PC. before installin i found this page http://praveenpuglia.com/make-wamp-work-on-windows-10-technical-preview/ , and i after i installed Visual C++ Redistributable and disabled Word Wide Web Publishing Service, Wamp installation completed with no problems and it works properly. still on my 1st pc problem remains even after i uninstalled wamp and installed it again after installing visual c++ redistributable first. ill try to undo everything before i installed wamp for first time and install it like on 2nd pc.